# How to set fixed view position across different locals?

Tags: android, xml

I'm currently working on an app and set up another local in strings.xml
I have a list view with three elements two text views and an image view 
when I change the language to something like Arabic the items positions change and they appear from right to left.
that messes up the whole layout.
My question is *how to set the position to fixed value so they don't change* 

 I tried searching for solutions for this problem but didn't get any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you should do it. Because people in other parts of the world read from right to left. For them it is totally normal and fine.

Anyway. To have **always** a LTR (Left-To-Right) layout you have to disabled the RTL (Right-To-Left) attribute in your `AndroidManifest`.

```
<application supportrtl="false" />
```

See also [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl) or [this blogpost](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) for more.

Comment: why I need it is a little complicated,anyways it got the job done. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make some views in a layout always in LTR, or RTL or whatever, regardless of their parent:

```
<LinearLayout
...
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
.../>
```